Which graph transformations affect/ change the domain and range of a function?
There are mainly the following types of graph transformation:

Vertical/ Horizontal Shift

Vertical/ Horizontal Stretch/ Compression

Reflection


Now which one of these transformations can affect the function's domain and range? Because I checked for Vertical/ Horizontal Stretch/ Compression, and it doesn't affect the domain or range of a function, whereas the other types of transformation does affect either domain or range. Is this true?
And is there any example where a single type of transformation affects both the domain and range?

Of course, any vertical transformation—whether it's a shift, stretch, or flip—will affect the range, the set of outputs of the function that determine the vertical coordinates of points on the graph. And analogously with horizontal transformation and the domain.

@SammyBlack I tried on multiple functions, the stretch/ compression doesn't affect domain or range

It certainly does! Take $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ for example, whose graph is the upper semicircle of unit radius. Domain is $[-1, 1]$ and range is $[0, 1]$. Both of these will change if you stretch it into an ellipse. Try it here.

Think of the range as the shadow cast by the graph onto the vertical axis by light shining horizontally from either side. Analogously, think of the domain as the shadow cast by the graph onto the horizontal axis by light shining vertically from above and below.

1: Vertical/horizontal shifts affect the range and domain respectively, unless the function is infinitely long in the vertical direction where it wont change the range, or in the horizontal direction, in which the domain will remain unchanged.
2:Vertical stretch/compression will have an effect on the range as long as the range isnt -infinite<y<infinite. Same for horizontal with domain.
3:Reflection could have an effect on the domain and range in some cases, if the function isn't symmetrical around the axis that it is being reflected on.
In terms of a single transformation affecting both domain and range, think of a line y=x, and then reflecting a function on that line, it could potentially have an effect on both domain and range.
